# SSD settings under UBUNTU 14.04,

Tags: 14.04, ssd, settings

I have just set up a NEC with ubuntu 14.04 amd 64, the hard drive is the SanDisk Ultra II SSD. I have found some information on [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd#TOC-Avoid-quick-wear:-reduce-write-actions), and it is different from what I have read elsewhere. Elsewhere it just stated to add

noatime,discard,

to the errors=remount line.

So,

---

- should I "Reserve seven percent [of the hard drive] for overprovisioning", and can I do this still (after already having installed the system without such

---

- in that web page they seem to say that discard is a trim action, and that the preferred version of a trim is by writing in the /etc/rc.local file

fstrim -v

Is this indeed better than discard in fstab? I think the PC would be rebooted once daily

---

- is there anything else that needs doing?

---

Thanks a lot!